# Windows 7 Installation Failure

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've researched compatibility, and all is a go with the hardware.  I've googled the subject, and found nothing.  Furthermore - no log file is generated!

Windows Home Premium 64-bit upgrade fails on a Gateway DX-4200. It's going all the way through the installation process, and when it reboots - nothing - and the monitor isn't getting a signal ("No Cable").  For this reason, I disabled the onboard video, plugged in a PCI-E card from another machine that accepted 7 flawlessly, and got the same result.

I plugged the drive into another machine and looked for the setuperr.log (Yes, I know the $windows...\panther... ) but it doesn't exist!

Swapped out RAM - same result.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it without upgrading? I know you have upgrade media, but there are ways to install without upgrading:

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp

Comment: I'll let you know how this works out - thank you.

Comment: It worked!  I don't know *why* it worked, but the fresh install did.
What's really puzzling is the lack of any logs created during the fails to at least give us a clue.  Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! I always prefer to do clean installs myself. It's just something about upgrading such a hugely complex piece of software... Eeek!

Answer (score 1):

drive could be faulty.  Or windows setup is corrupt.  Try reinstall?

Comment: Drive tested fine. Drive was wiped using WipeDrive, as well, installed with a clean Vista, then reinstall has been tried no less than 4 times.  I should also mention that this system has been running Vista without incident since May '09.